# Does producing a heavy nucleus release more energy than producing two lighter nuclei with the same number of protons and neutrons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

Does producing a heavy nucleus release more energy than producing two lighter nuclei with the same number of protons and neutrons? If this holds true what is the reason behind this?

Say we have 20 protons and 20 neutrons. Which of the following releases more energy?

- The production of one Ca-40 nucleus

OR

- The production of two nuclei, each with half as many nucleons. In this case: two Ne-20 atoms

PS: I am a high school student with some knowledge about binding energy and the concept of relativity.

Comment: Google ‘Atomic mass evaluation 2020’ - part 2 has the atomic mass tables including binding energies for you to compare various combinations.

Comment: I did. But I still don’t understand why producing a heavy nucleus “always” releases more energy

Comment: Although one would have to go through a specific calculation to be sure, fusion for the most part releases energy until you reach iron-$56$ or so ([where binding energy per nucleon peaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve)), which suggests $2{}^{20}\operatorname{Ne}\to{}^{40}\operatorname{Ca}$ releases energy.

Comment: For fun you could compare one Ca-40 vs 10 He-4.

Comment: And how can I do that?